# Wrong document ID after Save/Read

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

In an ASP.NET Core application (with MongoDb) I am trying to retrieve a document that I just created before.

Here is my document (POCO):

```
public class Person
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        this.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId();
    }
}
```

My ASP.NET Core controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMongoDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(IMongoDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var repository = new Repository(_context);

        var personX = await repository.CreatePersonAsync(name: "John created at " + DateTime.Now.ToFileTimeUtc());

        var personY = await repository.GetPersonByIdAsync(personX.Id);

        return View();
    }
}
```

Finally in my repository class:

```
   public async Task<Person> CreatePersonAsync(string name)
    {
        var person = new Person() { Name = name };

        var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq("_id", person.Id);

        var saveResult = await this.PersonCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, person, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });

        return person;
    }

    public async Task<Person> GetPersonByIdAsync(ObjectId id)
    {
        var person = await this.PersonCollection.Find(x => x.Id.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return person;
    }
```

When debugging my application in Visual Studio 2017 CE:

1. personX: Id = {5a3b81ceff702421e00c5c7**e**}, Name = "John created at 131583228941663577"
2. personY: Id = {5a3b81ceff702421e00c5c7**f**}, Name = "John created at 131583228941663577"

While the Name values are identical, the Ids are slightly different. **Why?** What am I missing?

It's probably something about async/await that I messed up, because everything works fine if I do everything synchronously.

Thanks for any help, guys!

ASP.NET Core 2, MongoDb.Driver 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your `Person` class. `Id` property does not have a setter, it's just initialized in constructor with value of `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()`. That's why when `GetPersonByIdAsync()` is called, MongoDB driver could not fill `Id` property with value stored in the database and it's filled with new id generated with `ObjectId.GenerateNewId()`.

To fix the problem add a public setter to `Id` property. I also suggest not to fill it in constructor. Just fill it when you create new `Person` instance for adding to the database:

```
public class Person
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public async Task<Person> CreatePersonAsync(string name)
{
    var person = new Person()
    {
        Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(),
        Name = name,
    };

    var filter = Builders<Person>.Filter.Eq("_id", person.Id);

    var saveResult = await this.PersonCollection.ReplaceOneAsync(filter, person, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });

    return person;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, oh my god. What can I give you? Do you need a new car or something? ;) This thing is driving me nuts since days ... forest for the trees. Thanks so much!